# why is my mesh black in blender even though the color is set to white

Tags: blender

[image: enter code here]

I set my mesh black then wanted to set it back to white but can't. How do i do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Game Development Stack Exchange. As this Blender question is not specific to game development and entirely relates to Blender it would be better on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This would be clearer to answer if you also showed the material tab in the properties window, but it could be that you've changed the ViewPort Display Color to black, which overrides the material color when you're not in rendered view mode.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your normals are backword try recalculating them.

Select your object and use ctrl + N.